# How to add AUDs to HEVC using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I have a HEVC 4k mkv missing AUD units and want to use ffmpeg to add them in (without re-encoding).  I came up with:

```
ffmpeg -i Movie.mkv -c:v libx265 -c copy -map v -x265-params aud=1 Movie.ts
```

But it didn't add in AUD so there's something wrong in there (possibly jus in the wrong order?) and I’ve tried a bunch of different combinations.

Comment: Stream copy means stream copy. Not stream copy-but-modify.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for that. I can't really understand what you mean by that though, I guess I don't know as much as I thought I did. I still can't figure out the correct code for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a bitstream filter, specifically `hevc_metadata`. Bitstream filters operate upon coded streams so they can be applied during stream copy or on the result from an encoder.

In your case, it's possibly to insert AUD NALUs without re-encoding. Use

```
ffmpeg -i Movie.mkv -c copy -bsf:v hevc_metadata=aud=insert Movie.ts
```

See docs at http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-bitstream-filters.html#hevc_005fmetadata

Comment: Thanks but the ts file video seems to not work anymore after using that line of code. It won't play in VLC and tsMuxer says "Track 0 was not recognised and ignored." I'll see if I can demux the original and just run the video file through...

Comment: So I figured maybe having more than one audio track might be a problem so I demuxed with just one video and one audio track. Ran the code again and the video now works but there's still no-aud in the metadata so I'm not sure the code worked or again I'm doing something wrong.

'''[mpegts @ 0x7febf8808600] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly'''

Comment: Sadly can't get this code to work. Does anyone else have any other suggestions I can try? Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: Works here. Can you share the source? Which ffmpeg version?

Comment: It's a 60GB file so can't be easily shared. The format for it is HEVC Mail 10@5.1High with a bitrate of 60.9 Mb/s and it has multiple audio channels. I'm using ffmpeg-101541-g5282147d0c

Comment: You can generate a snippet: `ffmpeg -i input -c copy -t 30 snippet.mkv`

Comment: Ok I have done, I've emailed it through using the address in your profile. I hope that's OK.

Comment: Sure. I'll look at it in one or two days.

Comment: Many thanks for your time!

Comment: It does work. Command used is `ffmpeg -i snippet.mkv -map 0 -c copy -bsf:v hevc_metadata=aud=insert snippet_with_auds.mkv`. See output and logs at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1A0UX41g8W8c66wt5LRY9-d0feCswLTVI?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for testing that for me Gyan, I guess the problem I have is that media info still mentions 'no-aud' in that file and any file output using that command. Maybe media info just can't pick up that it has had aud inserted or isn't a good way to check if it does. Is there any software that could show aud is present in a file?

Comment: What software is complaining about no AUDS and how are you checking about them?

Comment: Nothing is complaining but as I understand it, AUDs are required for Blu-ray video discs. The only way I can think to check if AUDs are there is via mediainfo but that says no-aud on both my file and the one you sent. It has omitted the 'no' bit on other bd video files so perhaps the AUDs aren't added in though I don't know if mediainfo is a good way to check.

Comment: Share the readout from mediainfo where this is mentioned.

Comment: It's under encoding settings:

Encoding settings                        : cpuid=1049583 / frame-threads=4 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=3840x2160 / interlace=0 / total-frames=0 / level-idc=51 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=4 / no-allow-non-conformance / no-repeat-headers / annexb / no-aud / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / 

I've took a screenshot as well:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nc5tfbala6j32mp/no-aud.jpg?dl=0

Comment: That registers the value of `aud` parameter during its encoding and not the presence/absence of AUDs in the stream at the current time.

Comment: Oh right, well that's good to know! Thanks for your patience. Is there any way to check if a file has AUDs? How would anyone ever know?

Comment: That no-aud is part of of original uregistered user SEI that x265 created for info only. It does not matter, it is not used in this case.